# How fast can I send data to firebase from nodemcu 1.0?

Tags: esp8266, arduino

I was sending some variable value to the firebase database I have created: how fast can I send it? What would be minimum time interval between two values nodemcu can send and fire base can receive? I was counting IV fluid(saline bottle)drip rate and sending rate value to database, what can I do so that my mcu would not miss any drop count?

Comment: you can probably have a counter set up and count the value and at a particular interval of time, you can upload it to the database. You can store the data in EEPROM/SPIFFS if there is any chance of internet connectivity loss and can store the count of that particular interval of time and when an Internet connection is up you can send all data together by this you will have data with periodic time. And I think the time interval of firebase is like 10sec min.

Answer (score 1):

There are many different possible limits:

- limits of Firebase, as well as limits for the Firebase free quota. You can find them here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas

  They include a 20000 document writes per day limit on the free quota and a 1 write per document per second limit. There are also limits in terms of amount of data and more. Of course, depending on how many devices you have and the granularity you need, this may be either plentiful or very little.
- limits of your hardware (sensor etc.), of which we don’t know much
- limits of your network connection. Not quite the same thing if you send the data over LoRa, BLE, Zigbee or NB-IoT on one hand, or over Wi-Fi or Ethernet on the other, with lots of other possibilities in between, and of course other links on the path between your MCU and Firebase. You’re probably using WiFi, but we lack a lot of details.

As commented by Lucifer, you should probably aggregate data over intervals rather than each drop individually, but that really depends on what you are actually trying to measure.